# Checkbox issue with asp.net mvc 3 - missing assembly reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

In my HTML (The view) I have

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="car-required" id="car-required" value="1" />CAR required
```

I get a run time error of CAR missing assembly or refence...What gives? It seems to treat my text on the html form as C# code....

Is there an ASP.net MVC specific way to write html for a simple checkbox?
Thanks!

EDITED
It is contained within @using block

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-frm" })) {
```

Curiously, if I put exact same mark up outside the @using, it works fine. Clearly, MVC 3 bug, as HTML is not supposed to give c# error

Comment: What's the exact message and stack trace? HTML cannot give an error.

Comment: Can you post the portion of your view that this is contained in?  I'm guessing it has to do with the surrounding markup, as when I put that `<input />` control in a test page it renders fine with no error.

Comment: see my edit, SLacks - I know. Which is why it is annoying and bewildering.

Comment: I solved the issue by wrapping the text into a span tag...moving on.

Comment: You're misunderstanding Razor's code contexts.  See Darin's answer.

Comment: It's not so much of "misunderstanding" as it is Razor falling short to parse perfectly valid html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Razor parser tries to do as best as it can but in this case it simply falls short. So you can help him by using `@:` or wrapping the in `<text>` nodes (which is a special kind of node for the parser indicating text literal. The `<text>` node is obviously not rendered in the output):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-frm" })) 
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="car-required" id="car-required" value="1" />@:CAR required
}
```

or:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-frm" })) 
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="car-required" id="car-required" value="1" /><text>CAR required</text>
}
```